# using sass color functions without sass engine

Tags: ruby, sass

I want to use Sass color functions within a class, without the Sass Engine. I'm already using the sass gem in the project so i thought piggy-backing would be something as easy as:

```rb
class Rectangle
  include Sass::Script::Functions
  def color
    Sass::Script::Color.new([0x82, 0x39, 0x06])
  end
  def render
    #haml engine executed with context of self
    #so that within temlate i could call
    #  %stop{offset: '0%', stop: {color: lighten(color)}}
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:** see `#render` above, i want to call `lighten(color)` from within a haml template rendered within the context of a `Rectangle` instance

But i get an undefined method `assert_type` error. The `assert_type` method is defined within the `Sass::Script::Functions::EvaluationContext` class. ([github file](https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/stable/lib/sass/script/functions.rb))

Playing around in `irb`, just to get something close to what i want looks like this:

```rb
require 'sass'
eval_context = Sass::Script::Functions::EvaluationContext.new({})
#yes the Sass::Script::Number.new(10) is requried, a simple 10 will not work
color = eval_context.rgb(Sass::Script::Number.new(10), Sass::Script::Number.new(10), Sass::Script::Number.new(10))
eval_context.lighten(color, Sass::Script::Number.new(10))
```

which is crazy - am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Now that I understand your problem better, why not just rewrite the functionality.

```
require 'sass'

class Rectangle
  include Sass::Script

  def color
    @color ||= Sass::Script::Color.new([0x82, 0x39, 0x06])
  end

  def lighten(ammount)
    hsl = color.hsl.dup
    hsl[2] += ammount
    @color = Sass::Script::Color.new(hue: hsl[0], saturation: hsl[1], lightness: [2])
  end
end

rec = Rectangle.new
rec.lighten(20)
```

**Old Answer**

You aren't crazy, you've just included the wrong piece.

This code runs as you expect it. Notice that I removed the `::Functions` from the include.

```
require 'sass'

class Rectangle
  include Sass::Script

  def color
    color = Sass::Script::Color.new([0x82, 0x39, 0x06])
    puts color.class
  end
end

rec = Rectangle.new
rec.color
```

Comment: sorry - i guess my real question was buried in my code comments. i want to call rec.lighten(rec.color, 10) - i'll update my question.

Also i can raise an error in your code: if you remove the `puts` statement from the `#color` method and replace the final line with puts `rec.color`

Comment: thanks. still errors on `puts` though, or rather on `#to_s`. `#to_s` needs to work as that is what the haml template will call. To fix this the `@color` variable needs options set to something. `@color.options={}` seems to work.
I'll accept your answer, i just wish sass was more modular - it seems very tied to the "engine"

Comment: Well, Sass is at it's heart a CSS engine. What is the purpose for using it this way?

Comment: to manipulate colors. i'm absolutely positive there is another gem out there to do this, but like i said, i already have the sass gem loaded...

Comment: fyi Color.new needs hash argument for hsl, otherwise they are considered rgb values `@color = Sass::Script::Color.new(hue: hsl[0], saturation: hsl[1], lightness: hsl[2])`

Comment: Interesting. On both counts.

Comment: think you could update the `Color.new(hsl)` code in your answer to use hash arguments? like in the comment above. thanks

Answer (score 5):

Sass::Script::Parser.parse('lighten(#333, 10)', 0, 0).perform(Sass::Environment.new)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. It's been 3 years since this answer. Is there any other way to achieve this? or this is it?